# Set cron job in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cpanel

I am trying to run a script via **cron** job in **cpanel**. Maybe I entered a wrong path that's why I received a mail:

> could not open input file.

Here is my code

```
class Cron extends CI_Controller
{

    public function run()
    {
        $this->load->library('email');   
        $this->email->to('to@mail.com');
        $this->email->from('from@mail.com','From');
        $this->email->subject('Cron');
        $this->email->message('Hello);
        $this->email->send();
    }
}
```

**This code available in**

`public_html/folder/myproject/application/controller/Cron.php`

But I dont know how to set this path in cron url

Comment: you have to put path in server not in codeigniter.

Comment: Yes,But i run this script.How to set this path?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following in cpanel command input

```
wget -q -O - http://www.yourdomain.com/cron/run >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Check the Screenshot
[image]

If you want to do the same thing by file then please use proper path

```
/home/youruserdirectory/public_html/folder/myproject/application/controller/Cron.php
```

replace `youruserdirectory` to your current user directory.

Hope it will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your code the `Cron` controller has to be called from the web, not from command line, but that's fine, you don't necessarily have to provide cron job with the path on the server. You can run a command to make a request to your site like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -qO- https://example.com/cron
```

The command in the example will make a request to your site every 5 minutes effectively running the `Cron` controller every time (in case you have not prevented access to it by its name with routing).